# Saving an BufferedImage to raw bytes

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

Hello i want to Saving an BufferedImage to raw bytes
i do this for the moment

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData);
BufferedImage image = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(in);
BufferedImage imageModifier = ResizeImage.resize(image, 10, 10);
```

but know i want to save my file so i don(t know how to convert for do this

```
FileOutputStream fileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(fileToCreate);
fileOutStream.write(fileData);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code is confusing.  Why do you have a variable called `fileData` and why are you using `FileOutputStream` when you are trying to write to raw bytes?  (Which I assume you mean byte array?)

If what you really want is to save a BufferedImage to file use `javax.imageio.ImageIO`

Comment: byte[] fileData  = newfile.getFileData();

when i've got my fileData i convert to BufferedImage  for resize my image and when i rezie my image i write into a folder with the  FileOutputStream

Comment: Ok then read up on ImageIO, its what you need.

Also you don't need to use newFile.getFileData().  Just do `InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(<path to file>));`

Answer (score 1):

From the Java 2D trail: [Writing/Saving an Image](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html)